# Q: aligning title "high" forces graph to be smaller, how do I keep the graph width?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Trying to align the `yAxis.title` at the top of the axis, but even though I rotate and give it `x: 250` it still "takes space" on the left and making the graph smaller. How do I keep the width of the graph?

this image is without giving x offset value, but the space that is "actually takes" is still there.
[image: graph image]

```
title: {
    align: "high",
    offset: 0,
    text: tag,
    rotation: 0
    y: -10,
    // x: 250,
},
```

Comment: Working for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/8kom415y/ can you make a fiddle? Make sure you don't have any kind of left margin set, of course. Strip out anything that could confound the issue and add back in one by one...

Comment: I went with a different approach, but I tried removing all options that could even affect title, still did not work. Might have been an issue with the container using flex?

Comment: Please provide a live demo (jsfiddle ideally) that recreates this issue.